# Give access to Sql developer to Documents Folder

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, macos-catalina

Firstable, i don't know if this is the best place to ask this.

I made a clean Catalina OSX (10.15.7) install, and i'm trying to access to Document Folder using Sql Developer, but i don't know what is the problem.

If you see the image, this is the error:

[image]

I'm using java version "11.0.9" 2020-10-20 LTS

What is wrong?

Folder permissions

[image]

Best regards

**UPDATE:**

The same error with other folders

[image]

Comment: Does it open any other folder?

Comment: i update my question, but is the same error

Answer (score 8):

Go to `System Preferences` → `Security & Privacy` → `Privacy` → `Full Disk Access`.

Click add (`[+]`) and grant access to `/bin/bash`.

Comment: After clicking on the [+] icon, if you are not able to navigate to /bin folder, then open a new Finder window. Hit on Go in the menu bar. Then Click on Go to Folder. Then type in /bin/bash and hit Enter. Then drag the bash icon over to the System Preferences window.

Comment: @SanthoshJose , Thanks, this is what I had to do on my mac as of July 26th 2022. (I know comments have a time stamp)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, same Error here.

Installed Java 11 and SQL-Developer "20.2..." on a fresh macOS Big Sur (also tested it with a fresh install of macOS Catalina).

Can't access my desktop-, documents-, downloads-directory and /home through the import/open-dialog of SQL-Dev. Other directories can be accessed.

In the macOS-privacy-settings I granted Java 11 to full access my drive.

Starting the SQL-Developer manuell via sudo "solves" the problem.